# Determine the distribution of $\Theta$ (Finding the range)

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have a two-dimensional normal distribution with
means $0$, variances 1, and correlation coefficient $\rho$, $|\rho| < 1$. Let $(R, \Theta)$ be
the polar coordinates.

Determine the distribution of $\Theta$.

---

I found the joint to be $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}}r\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}r^2(1-\rho \sin(2\theta)) \right\}$$

In order to obtain $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$ I need to take the marginal of the joint, by doing $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}}r\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}r^2\big(1-\rho \sin(2\theta)\big)\right\}dr$$
I've done so, by making the joint  look like the pdf of a gamma distro: also,  after setting $u=r^2$, $du=2rdr$ I get
$$
\begin{split}
f_{\Theta}(\theta)&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \exp\left\{-u\left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}\big(1-\rho \sin(2\theta)\big) \right)\right\}dr\\
&=\frac{1-\rho^2}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}(1-\rho \sin(2\theta))}
\end{split}
$$

But I can't find the range and that is my usual problem.
Any tip or trick on how to find the correct range on these type of problems would be more than welcome!

Do I just use my calculus knowledge to find the domain of f?

Comment: You can think about it intuitively first: $(X,Y)$ can be 'any' point in the 2D plane (since the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$ is positive everywhere in the 2D plane), so in particular we can get a point at any angle, so $\Theta$ should be able to represent any angle (for example take values in $(-\pi,\pi]$).

Comment: Support of $\Theta$ is just the range of values the angle $\theta$ takes in the usual polar transformation $(x,y)\to(r,\theta)$ with $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$. So you could say $0<\Theta<2\pi$ or $-\pi<\Theta<\pi$ with probability one.